# Finding "Application Stop Events" in Azure Application insights

Tags: azure, logging, azure-application-insights

I have a web application that sometimes undergoes "Platform (Infrastructure Upgrade)" events.

The only way that I can detect these is by going to the Azure portal and drilling down

- **Diagnose and Solve Problems > Web App Restarted**

and looking for errors such as below

[image]

My question really, is can I use Application Insights to query Azure to find out when these events happen?

Seems like a simple thing to do, but can't figure it out to do it.

Comment: Peter is correct. @PeterBons can you please post it as answer?

Answer (score 1):

> can I use Application Insights to query Azure to find out when these events happen?

No, but your application is maybe able to log an event upon start or close? For example, in a .Net Core app you can listen to stop/start events like [this](https://github.com/Ibis-Software/AppInsightsDemo/blob/master/src/AppInsightDemo/Startup.cs#L48):

```cs
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime, TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
{
    hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => { telemetryClient.TrackEvent("App Started"); });
    hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => { telemetryClient.TrackEvent("App Stopping"); });
    hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => {
        telemetryClient.TrackEvent("App Stopped");
        telemetryClient.Flush();

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

It uses the [IHostApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) interface to get notified of application lifetime events.